# Array Shrink Wrap Curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

tell me pls best way to make this holes
on grey path  it's like insert then looptools
On yellow path i want to try shrinkWrap and array mod along that curves 
[image]

OR tell me please how to make this faces with the same size then apply insert and looptools
[image]

Comment: I guess using a Boolean operation is not desirable because of all the odd triangles it makes?

Answer (score 2):

Select the face and snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*). Then delete the face (press <kbd>X</kbd>).
[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num 7</kbd> to align the view to selected face. In *Edit Mode* add a *plane* and align it to view (check the ***Align to View*** box in *Tool Shelf*).
[image]

Scale the *plane* to achieve a desired size of the hole and connect the vertices of your helmet mesh to it. Next delete the newly created face.
[image]

Now you've got a regular hole.
[image]